# Programme executes in strange order

Tags: c, linux

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define DEBUG
int main()
{
     #ifdef DEBUG 
     freopen("ddd.txt","a",stdout);
     freopen("ddd.txt","a",stderr);
     #endif
     printf("1\n");
     perror("2");
     printf("3\n");
     perror("4");
     printf("5\n");
     perror("6"); 
 }
```

As @JonathanLeffler notes, on Mac OS X 10.10.1 with GCC 4.9.1 this gives:

```
2: Undefined error: 0
4: Undefined error: 0
6: Undefined error: 0
1
3
5
```

Why the strange order?

Also, `perror` is returning "invalid argument" as the error. Is it safe to use `freopen` on the same file?

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Guessing the question was wrongly formatted and what he needs to know is "is it safe to use freopen on same file?"

Comment: Please include all the information in your question, *including the output you would like explained*.  Answerers should not have to reverse-engineer your question.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The output I get on Mac OS X 10.10.1 with GCC 4.9.1 is:

```
2: Undefined error: 0
4: Undefined error: 0
6: Undefined error: 0
1
3
5
```

The sequence is like that because standard error is not buffered and standard output is buffered.

There could be any number of reasons why you get error EINVAL, Invalid argument.  Unless `freopen()` returned an error indication, you have no cause to be checking the value in `errno`; library functions are allowed to set `errno` even when they succeed.  (For example, on Solaris, many output operations would leave `errno` set to ENOTTY, Not a tty, when the output was to something other than a terminal, even though the operation was successful.)

Note that you should, strictly, check the return value from [`freopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html) is not NULL before you use the stream.  The call could fail if the file cannot be created or is not writable or is a directory, etc.

And to address your question:

> Is it safe to use freopen on the same file?

It depends on your definition of 'safe'.  Will your computer blow up?  No, not just because of that. Will `freopen()` fail on the second attempt?  No, it doesn't.  Could you get interesting interleaving effects with the data?  Yes, certainly.  Blocks of standard output, not necessarily ending with a newline, could easily be interleaved with lines of standard error. Would you often do this?  No, you would not often do this.  And if you do, you might want to set both standard output and standard error to line buffered with [`setvbuf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) immediately after the calls to `freopen()`.  This would reduce the amount of odd-seeming output.